# What's the difference between the single dash and double dash flags on shell commands?

Tags: shell

I'm new to working in the shell and the usage of these commands seems arbitrary. Is there a reason one flag has a single dash and another might have a double dash?

Comment: That link is now 404 @cjc :( A possibly more reliable link could be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX

Comment: Better link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Option_conventions_in_Unix-like_systems

Answer (score 164, accepted):

A single hyphen can be followed by multiple single-character flags.  A double hyphen prefixes a single, multicharacter option.

Consider this example:

```
tar -czf
```

In this example, `-czf` specifies three single-character flags: `c`, `z`, and `f`.

Now consider another example:

```
tar --exclude
```

In this case, `--exclude` specifies a single, multicharacter option named `exclude`.  The double hyphen disambiguates the command-line argument, ensuring that `tar` interprets it as `exclude` rather than a combination of `e`, `x`, `c`, `l`, `u`, `d`, and `e`.

Comment: Ohh... totally makes sense. Would `tar --c` also be recognized?

Comment: @kylex, no, since there is no long option named just "c" and the -- means a long option, not a single character option follows.

Comment: Sometimes even long commands can be single-dashed. For example 'cdrecord' uses all single-dashed commands (-eject -dao ...). It all depends on the program, but most(!) of them use - for single and -- for multiple-character (long) commands

Comment: @mulaz, yes, cdrecord does quite a few goofy things.

Comment: Right, the API for developers for working with command-line parameters under POSIX systems like Linux (and under Windows as well) in C is pretty crappy.  Mostly they just expect you to [know the conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02) and manually code your program to conform to them *(made worse by non-standard but common conventions like this one)*, leading to *a lot* of programs that half-conform and have lots of essentially duplicated code.  But unfortunately, that's the way things tend to be in C.

Comment: @BlueRaja, not so.  There is the getopt() api, and the GNU extension: getopt_long(), which is what most apps use these days, and where the double dash comes from.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt

Comment: @psusi: Yes, I am aware of `getopt()` and have used it many times.  However, it still leaves conforming to conventions a largely manual process.  And `getopt_long()` is not very widely used outside of the built-in Linux utilities, as it is not portable (it's non-POSIX).

Comment: also bear in mind -- used on its own usually signifys the end of options. see here for more info: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean

Comment: Best answer i have seen so far

Comment: So why is it java -version and ant -version, then ?

Comment: @killjoy, because whether through ignorance or choice, the authors of those programs did not follow the convention of course.  Just like `cdrecord` mentioned years ago in the above comments.

Comment: First time I read a clear definition of -- !

Answer (score 28):

It all depends on the program. Usually "-" is used for 'short' options (one-letter, -h), and "--" is used for "long"(er) options (--help).

Short options can usually be combined (so "-h -a" is same as "-ha")

> In Unix-like systems, the ASCII hyphen–minus is commonly used to specify options. The character is usually followed by one or more letters. An argument that is a single hyphen–minus by itself without any letters usually specifies that a program should handle data coming from the standard input or send data to the standard output. Two hyphen–minus characters ( -- ) are used on some programs to specify "long options" where more descriptive option names are used. This is a common feature of GNU software.

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments)

Comment: So why is it java -version and ant -version, then ?

Comment: @killjoy Because those are no UNIX commands and software developers are free to make their programs follow different rules than those of traditional UNIX commands.

Answer (score 13):

It's really a convention. However, it can aid parsers to know more efficiently about options passed to the program.
Besides, there are neat utilities that can help parsing these commands, such as [`getopt(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getopt.html) or the non-standard [`getopt_long(3)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) to help parse the arguments of a program.

It is nice, for we can have multiple short options combined, as other answers say, like `tar -xzf myfile.tar.gz`.

If there was a "lisa" argument for `ls`, there would probably have a different meaning to type `ls -lisa` than `ls --lisa`. The former are the `l`, `i`, `s`, and `a` parameters, not the word.

In fact, you could write `ls -l -i -s -a`, meaning exactly the same as `ls -lisa`, but that would depend on the program.

There are also programs that don't obey this convention. Most notably for my sight, `dd` and `gcc`.

Answer (score 7):

> short options with single dash vs long options with double dash

short options can be combined into a single argument;

```
for example: ls -lrt #instead of ls -l -r -t
```

If we allow long options with single dash, it causes ambiguity. To resolve this we use double dash for long options.

Answer (score 0):

Another case is when a script calls another program, it may be necessary to separate the options for the first script from those passed to the second program. For example, you can write a bash function to parse the command line, similar to the function below.  Then use a command line similar to the following.  In this case the double dashes keep the options for each program separated and allows the built-in parser's error handling to work as intended.  Of course, there may special cases that would need to be handled.

```
 firstscript --firstScriptOption -- --optForSecondProgram
```

```
# Parse the command line and set variables to control logic.
parseCommandLine() {
  local additionalOpts exitCode optstring optstringLong
  # Indicate specification for single character options:
  # - 1 colon after an option indicates that an argument is required
  # - 2 colons after an option indicates that an argument is optional, must use -o=argument syntax
  optstring="h"
  # Indicate specification for long options:
  # - 1 colon after an option indicates that an argument is required
  # - 2 colons after an option indicates that an argument is optional, must use --option=argument syntax
  optstringLong="help"
  # Parse the options using getopt command:
  # - the -- is a separator between getopt options and parameters to be parsed
  # - output is simple space-delimited command line
  # - error message will be printed if unrecognized option or missing parameter but status will be 0
  # - if an optional argument is not specified, output will include empty string ''
  GETOPT_OUT=$(getopt --options ${optstring} --longoptions ${optstringLong} -- "$@")
  exitCode=$?
  if [ ${exitCode} -ne 0 ]; then
    # Call a separate function to print usage.
    printUsage
    exit 1
  fi
  # The following constructs the command by concatenating arguments:
  # - the $1, $2, etc. variables are set as if typed on the command line
  # - special cases like --option=value and missing optional arguments are generically handled
  #   as separate parameters so shift can be done below
  eval set -- "${GETOPT_OUT}"
  # Loop over the options:
  # - the error handling will catch cases were argument is missing
  # - shift over the known number of options/arguments
  while true; do
    #echo "Command line option is ${opt}"
    case "$1" in
      -h|--help) # Print usage of this script
        printUsage
        shift
        ;;
      --) # No more arguments - following arguments are passed to the second program.
        shift
        break
        ;;
      *) # Unknown option - will never get here because getopt catches up front
        # and remaining options are after --
        echo "Invalid option $1." >&2
        printUsage
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
  done
  # Get a list of all command line options that do not correspond to dash options:
  # - These are "non-option" arguments after --
  # - For example, one or more file or folder names that need to be processed.
  # - If multiple values, they will be delimited by spaces.
  # - Command line * will result in expansion to matching files and folders.
  shift $((OPTIND-1))
  additionalOpts=$*
  echo "Additional options: ${additionalOpts}"
  # The additional options would be passed to the second program.
}
```

Comment: this is different, the double hyphen in your example signifies the end of the command options, therefore, anything after it will be interpreted as text (not a command argument). In the example above, the `--optForSecondProgram` will be interpreted as text or filename (depending on the program).